# Determining the critical points of a $2D$ Fermi surface

Tags: condensed-matter, fermi-energy

Suppose I have a $2D$ Fermi surface like below:

[image]

How would I discern where its critical points would be without looking at an image this?

[image]

Here, since I know that, for instance, $X$ must be at the center of a square face, its position is clear to see. However, how would I know where to put $X$ (or any other critical point) without being able to refer to my second image?